# Html5 routing with Spring and Angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I'm trying to implement HTML5 routing with Spring-boot and Angular 1.5, following [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2015/05/13/modularizing-the-client-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-vii#using-ldquo-natural-rdquo-routes).

At some point I need to redirect all the angular routes to the base path with a controller like this:

```
@Controller
 public class UrlController {
  // Match everything without a suffix (so not a static resource)
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}"))
  public String redirect(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // Forward to home page so that route is preserved.
    return "forward:/";
  }
}
```

While the regular expression matches most of the URLS, like dashboard, search etc:

```
 2016-08-05 16:39:58 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:306 - Looking up handler method for path /dashboard
 2016-08-05 16:39:58 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:313 - Returning handler method UrlController.redirect(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String)]
 2016-08-05 16:39:58 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'urlController'
 2016-08-05 16:39:58 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:947 - Last-Modified value for [/dashboard] is: -1
 2016-08-05 16:39:58 DEBUG c.a.a.w.i.LoggingInterceptor:22 - Start processing url request: https://localhost:8443/dashboard
 redirecting to home page from url https://localhost:8443/dashboard
 2016-08-05 16:39:58 DEBUG c.a.a.w.i.LoggingInterceptor:35 - Finished processing url request: https://localhost:8443/dashboard, duration: 0[ms]
```

Others are ignored and not matched at all, like https://localhost:8443/faults/64539352

```
 2016-08-05 17:00:05 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/faults/64539352]
 2016-08-05 17:00:05 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:306 - Looking up handler method for path /faults/64539352
 2016-08-05 17:00:05 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:316 - Did not find handler method for [/faults/64539352]
```

The regular expression seems to be fine if you test it in [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)
, but it does not match what I want if I put it in the @RequestMapping. 
 Does anybody know how to make it work, or even better how to do it without regular expressions?

Comment: The problem seems to be when you use a second "/",  server/something is OK, but server/something/anythingElse does not match in any case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem and solution is described [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/issues/68#issuecomment-187675742). The solution consist in the implementation of a OncePerRequestFilter where you can match the full URI against whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correct *PathMatcher* to do the job: `{path:(?:(?!api|.).)*}/**`

More info [here](https://blog.impulsebyingeniance.io/software-technology/spring-boot-angular-comment-gerer-les-url-html-5/)