# Spring and React Router for URLs of form "/.../..."

Tags: reactjs, spring, react-router

I am using Spring for back-end with React for front-end and I am having React Router handle all the page routing on the front-end. To do this, I have the index controller below route all paths to "index.html", essentially allowing React to take over the routing. I am using the regex `/{path:[^\\.]*}` to route all paths and it works really well, except it only works for ".com/..." URL formats and not ".com/.../...". Anytime I set up a ".com/.../..." with React router, I get 404 errors similar to when I access an undefined endpoint.

```
    @Controller
    public class IndexController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}") //
        public String index(Map<String, Object> model) {
            return "index.html";
        }
    }
```

To clarify: endpoints such as ".com/api/users/1" that get the user with id 1 work perfectly because they are defined in my back-end controllers in the back-end, but I am having issues with `<Route exact path="/startuppage/:id" component={StartupPage} />` for example. I can't make this a back-end endpoint because I want to display a page at this URL and not just have it return some database object for example.

ReactJS code for my routes:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/database" component={Database} />
    <Route path="/submission" component={Submission} />
    <Route path="/submitted" component={Submitted} />
    <Route exact path="/startuppage/:id" component={StartupPage} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Could you please provide also the code of all your routes?

Comment: I just added the React Router routes. To clarify, "/database", "/submission", "/submitted" are static pages and "/startuppage/:id" I want to display a specific page tailored to a 'startup' object with 'id'

Comment: idk, I forked some sandbox and added a page with /startuppage/:id pattern and it seems to work (https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-forked-j02ny?file=/components/Main.js)
I also found someone with similar problem, maybe it will direct you to the solution, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792637/html5-routing-with-spring-and-angular